# How to select record from table1 where there is no payment entry yet?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have 2 tables in mysqli, I want to select all the customers from table1 where there is no payment entry in table2 yet or(specific date).

actually i am working on a customers payment system in php, and want to generate report about that customers that havent submit their installment according to due date.

Due date is 10th of every month.
how can i achieve that?

Edited for more detail:
1- In table1 I have bio data of customers
2- In table 2 entries of installment payments

customers have to pay an installment before 10th of every month.
when a customer submit his payment its entry will be inserted into table2.

Now, I want to notify the customers or make a report that havent submitted their installment before the 10th(or any due date) of current month.

have to make report so that recovery officer can get the list of customers that are late to submit their installment or to send the reminder to customers for upcoming installment payment.

my tables are

[image: Table 1]

[image: Table 2]

Comment: Your question is unclear.  How do you know what the due date is?  It is also unclear how the tables are related to each other.

Comment: due date is 10 of every month but i will specify it. lets say select * customers that that have not submitted installment payment yet. and due date is 6-10-2018, (coming 10 date of next month)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `not exists`.  You don't give quite enough information, but the idea would be:

```
set @duedate = ?;  -- whatever your logic is for this

select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.id = t1.id and t2.date > @duedate
                 );
```

EDIT:

From your comment, I surmise that you want:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.id = t1.id and
                        (day(curdate()) > 10 and
                         t.2 > curdate() + interval (10 - day(curdate)) day
                        ) or
                        (day(curdate()) > 10 and
                         t.2 > curdate() + interval (10 - day(curdate)) day - interval 1 month
                        )
                 );
```

Do note that this may not do anything helpful.  What about late payments?  This will count a previous late payment as being not overdue.

If this is an issue, I would recommend that you ask *another* question.  Put the sample data and desired results in *text tables* in the question.  Clearly explain the logic that you want, and any sample query is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

That what you are looking for is called a left join. You can achieve that by doing something along the lines of.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 On Table1.Key=Table2.Key WHERE Table2.Key IS NULL
```